# How to query for DBPointer's value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have this entry in database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5159c668a8f9718f040025da"), "name" : "foo", "subType" : DBPointer("Type", ObjectId("5159928ca8f9718f04000006")) ] }
```

The sub type references to:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5159928ca8f9718f04000006"), "name" : "Cafe" }
```

I want to do a query against the database, to find all records where the sub type's name is "Cafe". I've tried this, but does not work:

```
db.Entry.find({'subType.name': 'Cafe'})
```

I believe the reason why it doesn't work is because the reference is not fetched yet, how can I do that?

Comment: You can't.  A `find` query can only reference fields in the collection being queried.  What you're asking for is basically a join which isn't supported by MongoDB.

Comment: Without any background it's hard to say, but this should probably be embedded instead of "linked".

Comment: @xeraa Not embedded, because I want to be able to change the name of the sub type so that it changes automatically for every record that references it.